Spring WebSocket Issue: principal.getName()vs Target.getName() in convertAndSendToUser
I am a beginner in Spring, and I am working on a project with a frontend in React and a backend in Spring, using WebSocket for communication. Currently, I want to implement a feature to communicate with a specific user, but I encountered a strange issue. In my code, Target.getName() and principal.getName() have exactly the same result (so in this case, it is testing communication with itself). The only difference is that principal is a function parameter, possibly obtained directly from the communication (I guess); while Target is obtained from userManager. userManager is a singleton annotated with @Component, and it saves the principal information when the frontend connects to the backend.
When using the same Target.getName() and principal.getName(), messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser produces different outputs. When using principal.getName(), the frontend can receive the information normally, but when using Target.getName(), the frontend gets no response (does not receive the response information). I want to know the reason for this issue. If I can only use principal.getName(), how can I communicate with other clients, since principal only refers to the client sending the request?
@MessageMapping("/private-chat")
        public void handlePrivateChatMessage(Principal principal, @Payload PrivateChatMessage message) {
            Principal Target = userManager.findUser(message.getRecipient()).getPrincipal();
            if (Target != null) {
                System.out.println(Target.getName());
                System.out.println(principal.getName());
                try {
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(Target.getName(), "/queue/private", message);//didn't work
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/private", message);//it works
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error sending message to user {}: {}", message.getRecipient(), e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                logger.warn("No session ID found for user: {}", message.getRecipient());
            }
        }```


I have looked up many related issues, but they all seem to only explain why ***principal.getName() ***works and fail to explain why ***Target.getName()*** does not work.

